# Backup database with encryption

Tags: sql-server, encryption, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012. I am trying the query below for DB backup with encryption.

```
BACKUP DATABASE TestDB
TO DISK = 'C:\DEV\TestDB.bak' WITH 
DIFFERENTIAL,  ENCRYPTION (ALGORITHM = AES_256, SERVER CERTIFICATE = MyBackupCert)
```

But, it throws errors saying

> ENCRYPTION is not a recognized BACKUP option

How to format a query correclty to enable the backup with encryption?

THanks

Comment: What SQL Server version? `with encryption` requires SQL Server 2014 or later.

Comment: sql server 2012 R2. Is there a  way I can encrypt backup in sql server 2012 R2?

Comment: Well, there's your answer I'm afraid. You need to upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, [you need to upgrade to SQL Server 2014](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449489.aspx):

> Starting in SQL Server 2014, SQL Server has the ability to encrypt the data while creating a backup.

Alternatively, you could enable [Transparent Database Encryption](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934049(v=sql.110).aspx), which would encrypt the entire database, and so the backups would be encrypted too.

Or look for a third-party tool.